# Python socket: Make server & client wait for each other?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I´m trying to build a small console game with Python. One player plays as the client and the other one as the server.

Both the server and the client has to send input to the other player and must wait until both players submitted their input.

I got this worked out, but after both player submitted their input, I want them send each other their score, like this:

```
    scoreString = str(playerScore)
    scoreByte = bytearray(scoreString,"ascii")
    sock.send(scoreByte)
    otherPlayerScoreByte = sock.recv(1024)
    otherScore = int(otherPlayerScoreByte.decode("ascii"))
```

This part is identical for both the server and the client. What happens is that who ever submits their input first, the above code works correctly, but the other one gets stuck on this line:

```
 otherPlayerScoreByte = sock.recv(1024)
```

like it never receives the score from the other player.

Is their a way the check that the server/client has received their data before moving on?

Comment: "What happens is that who ever submits their input first, the above code works correctly"...so this has happened to both the "server" and the "client"?

Comment: Yes, the code works for whoever submits their input first.

Comment: I think you have to differentiate between server and client. When the server `send`s his score, the client must `recv`, then the client `send`s and the server `recv`es.

Comment: Well, flipping the order(meaning that the server receives before it sends) does not change things. Can I make something with a while-loop to make sure that the server receives the client score before sending its own?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? Error? Blocking call? I tried to reproduce your problem, but it worked even with `send`, `recv` in this sequence on both client and server. Maybe the problem is in another part of the code?